# Display/save data from a function to a txt file while using Tkinter GUI

Tags: function, tkinter, view, output, saving-data

I am still learning and I know there are many to do this; however, all I'm wanting to do is display and/or save what I usually print from my program functions in a a default text editor such as Notepad.

I understand how to get the file name and path from the user utilizing tkinter's filedialog module, however, I'm not sure how to place the data into that file.

For example, my program currently asks a user for an input range between whatever numbers they like, it then does some calculations and (as currently it is only a CLI) prints results. I'm trying to upgrade the program to have a simple interface that asks for the same initial range, but saves and/or opens the aforementioned calculations somehow.

I'd prefer to just open a default text editor and print them there. Then the user can choose to save or not those results using said text editors functionality.

Comment: Asking for a "best" way is going to yield opinionated answers, and asking opinions is off topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Edited the question. I only asked it that way as I'm sure there are more than several ways to do this.